# Invocation of Observer.onChanged() doesn't mean that content actually becomes different

Tags: android-architecture-components, observers, android-livedata

**Observation**

[The documentation of method `onChanged(T)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Observer#onChanged(T))
[image]

But, I found that trying to post the same data to a certain `LiveData`, `onChanged` will still be called.

---

**Experiment**

```
// member variable of an activity
val liveString = MutableLiveData<String>()

// onCreate
liveString.observe(this/*an activity*/, Observer { Log.d(TAG, it) })

// when a button is clicked
liveString.postValue("abc")
```

Then, click the button many times

---

**Result**
Even the posted string is always the same, the observer will be triggered every time.

Answer (score 1):

**Source code tracing**

[`LiveData.setValue`](http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/frameworks/support/lifecycle/livedata-core/src/main/java/androidx/lifecycle/LiveData.java#setValue)
→[`LiveData.dispatchingValue`](http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/frameworks/support/lifecycle/livedata-core/src/main/java/androidx/lifecycle/LiveData.java#dispatchingValue)
→[`LiveData.considerNotify`](http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/frameworks/support/lifecycle/livedata-core/src/main/java/androidx/lifecycle/LiveData.java#considerNotify)
→`Observer.onChanged`

There is no `Object.equals(Object)` checking in codeflow from `setValue` to `onChanged`

**Conclusion**

`onChanged` is called just because `LiveData<T>.setValue(T)` is ever called.
Therefore, even `onChanged(T)` is called, the underlying data may still be the same.

To achieve real "onChanged", you may use a `MediatorLiveData` to observe the original `LiveData`, and decide whether to forward the `onChanged` based on object equality check.